# Deploy failed when deploy:update_code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I have a rails app and wants to deploy to linode for first time, when I run `cap staging deploy:cold` to make a first deploy, I got failed when trigger `deploy:update_code` with cat revision error.

It's my log: https://gist.github.com/3349971
And it's my `deploy.rb` file: https://gist.github.com/3349968

Comment: From your log file, it looks like it's failing trying to create the REVISION file using a command line that explicitly references RVM. Is RVM installed on the target server?

Comment: Yes! and you can find I have rvm callback in my deploy.rb file to install/update rvm and ruby when every deploy and it can find in my log also. I have no idea why cat revision failed as you can see there is already pull from github and create the release also.